# NullPointer exception for parallel requests

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot, thread-safety

Can someone tell me what is wrong with this code

I get null pointer exception and I assume because of the multiple requests

```
@Service
public class GernericMockingServiceImpl implements GenericMockingService {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GernericMockingServiceImpl.class);

    @Override
    public String getJsonResponse(GenericMockingForm genericMockingForm, String requestURI) throws Exception {
        LOG.info("printing requestURI : "+requestURI);
        String path = new URI(requestURI).getPath();
        //resolves to a folder name in src/main/resources
        String folderName = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
        LOG.info("printing folderName : " + folderName);
        String jsonResponse = null;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        //check if the request body has prodcut id's which means that the request is for products else check for sku's which means that the request is for price or stock
        if(!Objects.isNull(genericMockingForm.getProductIds()) && !genericMockingForm.getProductIds().isEmpty()){
            //currently it iterates over all the product id's/sku's in the request and appends the content of all the id's
            //TODO: the content of the file is not exactly how we want it to be for multiple ids' But for the single id it just works.
            // TODO: Needs to be refactored later when we handle multiple id's in request
            for(String productId : genericMockingForm.getProductIds()){
                jsonResponse = getJson(folderName, productId, sb);
            }
        }else{
            for (String sku : genericMockingForm.getSkus()) {
                jsonResponse = getJson(folderName, sku, sb);
            }
        }
        LOG.info("printing jsonResponse : " + jsonResponse);
        return jsonResponse;
    }

    private String getJson(String folderName, String id, StringBuilder sb) throws Exception {
        String responseJson = null;
        String filePath = "data" + File.separator + folderName + File.separator + id + ".json";
        LOG.info("printing filePath : " + filePath);
        LOG.info("printing id : " + id);
        File f = new File(filePath);
        if(f.exists()){
            try (InputStream inputStream = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(filePath)) {
                LOG.info("printing inputStream : " + inputStream);
                if (inputStream != null) {
                    responseJson = IOUtils.toString(inputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
                }
                if (responseJson == null || responseJson.isEmpty()) {
                    LOG.info("json response is null : ");
                    throw new JsonNotFoundException(Constant.JSON_NOT_FOUND);   
                }
                sb.append(responseJson);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                LOG.info("IO exception : ");
                throw new IOException(e);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                LOG.info(" exception : ");
                throw new Exception(e);
            }
        }
        else{
            LOG.info("file doesnt exists : " + filePath);
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

**I have 3 parallel requests accessing a folder with 3 different files and trying to read from the files

This is my stack trace**

```
  2019-03-05 17:30:29.335  INFO 82 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.k.m.controller.ProductController       : Received request for Mocking Controller
    2019-03-05 17:30:29.335  INFO 82 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] c.k.m.controller.ProductController       : Received request for Mocking Controller
    2019-03-05 17:30:29.335  INFO 82 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] c.k.m.controller.ProductController       : Received request for Mocking Controller
    2019-03-05 17:30:29.336  INFO 82 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] c.k.m.s.impl.GernericMockingServiceImpl  : printing requestURI : /mocking/api/stocks
    2019-03-05 17:30:29.336  INFO 82 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] c.k.m.s.impl.GernericMockingServiceImpl  : printing requestURI : /mocking/get-products
    2019-03-05 17:30:29.337  INFO 82 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] c.k.m.s.impl.GernericMockingServiceImpl  : printing folderName : get-products
    2019-03-05 17:30:29.338  INFO 82 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] c.k.m.s.impl.GernericMockingServiceImpl  : printing filePath : data/get-products/1610-17637-319.json
    2019-03-05 17:30:29.338  INFO 82 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] c.k.m.s.impl.GernericMockingServiceImpl  : printing id : 1610-17637-319
    2019-03-05 17:30:29.338  INFO 82 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] c.k.m.s.impl.GernericMockingServiceImpl  : file doesnt exists : data/get-products/1610-17637-319.json
    2019-03-05 17:30:29.338  INFO 82 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] c.k.m.s.impl.GernericMockingServiceImpl  : printing jsonResponse : 
    2019-03-05 17:30:29.336  INFO 82 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.k.m.s.impl.GernericMockingServiceImpl  : printing requestURI : /mocking/api/prices
    2019-03-05 17:30:29.338  INFO 82 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.k.m.s.impl.GernericMockingServiceImpl  : printing folderName : prices
    2019-03-05 17:30:29.337  INFO 82 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] c.k.m.s.impl.GernericMockingServiceImpl  : printing folderName : stocks
    2019-03-05 17:30:29.343  INFO 82 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] c.k.m.s.impl.GernericMockingServiceImpl  : printing filePath : data/stocks/1610-17637.json
    2019-03-05 17:30:29.343  INFO 82 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] c.k.m.s.impl.GernericMockingServiceImpl  : printing id : 1610-17637
    2019-03-05 17:30:29.343  INFO 82 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] c.k.m.s.impl.GernericMockingServiceImpl  : file doesnt exists : data/stocks/1610-17637.json
    2019-03-05 17:30:29.343  INFO 82 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] c.k.m.s.impl.GernericMockingServiceImpl  : printing jsonResponse : 
    2019-03-05 17:30:29.354 ERROR 82 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause

    java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at com.kfz24.mockingservice.service.impl.GernericMockingServiceImpl.getJsonResponse(GernericMockingServiceImpl.java:45) ~[classes/:na]
        at com.kfz24.mockingservice.controller.GenericMockingController.processRequest(GenericMockingController.java:32) ~[classes/:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:189) ~[spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:800) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        **at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1038) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]**
```

Comment: Can you tell us the line where the exception occurs... or can you tell us which line is that `GernericMockingServiceImpl.java:45` in your code.

Comment: its this line  for (String sku : genericMockingForm.getSkus()) {

Comment: Basically the first request checks for Objects.isNull(genericMockingForm.getProductIds()) && !genericMockingForm.getProductIds().isEmpty() and then the another request checks for else block parallely

Comment: And this doesn’t happen with a single request only? It basically looks like the value returned by `getSkus()` is null. This will make the for-loop fail.

Comment: genericMockingForm can have either productId or sku at any point of time but it cant have both

Comment: /get-pruducts has productId and /api/skus has skus. and these api calls happens in parallel

Comment: Also I dont know if should be synchronizing some block of code

Answer (score 1):

> I get null pointer exception and I assume because of the multiple requests

I think your assumption is wrong.

> [From comments: the null is ] this line `for (String sku : genericMockingForm.getSkus()) {`

That seems to indicate that `genericMockingForm.getSkus()` is returning `null` since the only other object being used there is `genericMockingForm` which is tested above.

You should put the same null check on that form test:

```
 if (!Objects.isNull(genericMockingForm.getSkus())) ...
```

If both of them are `null` you then should spit out some sort of usage error.